# Non determinant -class operators satisfing $A^2+I=0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let  $H$  be  a  complex Hilbert space and  $A\in B(H)$ satisfies $A^2+I=0$. Does this implies that $A$ can be written in the form $A=\lambda I +T$ where $T$ is a trace classe operator  and $\lambda$ is  a complex scalar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not: Define $A:l^2\to l^2$ by
$$
Ax = i  (x_1,-x_2,x_3,-x_4,\dots).
$$
Then $A^2=-I$, but $A-\lambda I$ does not have finite trace for all $\lambda$.